# Passing data from 2 Tableviews to ViewController

Tags: swift3

I'm trying to pass data from tableView1 and tableView2 one at a time to MainVC via segues from textfields, the problem is MainVC.textField is not keeping the value of the previous tableView data, looks like is creating a new MainVC all the time, here is the code from the tableView which is the same for the second tableView.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

let indexPath = self.itemTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow

let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!) as! ItemCell

itemToPass = currentCell.itemName?.text

performSegue(withIdentifier: "toEnterItem", sender: self)

}
```

and

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

if segue.identifier == "toEnterItem" {

let enterItemVC = segue.destination as! MainVC

MainVC.passedItem = itemToPass
}

}
```

Any help will be appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, I used protocols to temporarily persist the data in textfields after segue.

```
protocol sendName {
 func sendToLastVC{name: String)
}
```